# powerBI map doesnt show cities

Tags: powerbi

Im trying to show provinces and then drill down to show cities in powerbi map (Aug, 2018 version).

My problem is it does show provinces but when I drill down to get a look at cities, it doesnt show anything.

I also changed column "city" to "place", but nothing happened.
(Note: they are Iran's province/cities, maybe this problem is related to that. because when I change for example my city "Kāshān" from province of "Isfahan" to "Redcar" or "London" it loads nicely on these two cities)

So, what is the solution?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new column called "Location" or "Place" by merging the City and Province columns. You can use a comma (,) as a separator. For example - "Alabama, USA".

Then change the category of the new column to Place. This will solve your issue. The map will be plotted correctly.